# RTextTools multi-label classification

Tags: machine-learning, r, text-mining, multilabel-classification

In follow up to my [previous question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9886/classifying-survey-response-text-svm), I was able to label survey responses based on 70 categories using RTextTools. Each survey gets one label while if manually coded some would have up to 8 labels.

The good news is my training data set does have multi-labels. So my question is, would be possible to train on 8 labels all at once? And then on the test data, get probabilities associated with each label and sort based on probability to get the top 8 labels?

Or can anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: Comment: It looks like the mlr package in R allows you to perform multi-label classification for anyone who is interested. My personal challenge is in data preparation and if anyone has any tips it would be very useful. Thanks