# Text Analysis to analyze qualitative (text based) Survey Results

Tags: machine-learning

I ran a survey asking this question: 'What do you like the most about your favorite character in the game?' and I got 23K responses; most of them are phrases/sentences; what's the best way to analyze these results such as to find out what the main responses are? A simple word cloud may not do because it strips out the context by isolating words; but I'm open. Would love help. Didn't know how to attached the dataset (my first time on Stack-Ex) so [here][1] it is. Thanks in advance fellow coders/analysts.

Comment: Check out Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA).  It's a probabilistic model for words that sorts words and responses into a pre-determined number of topics.

Comment: Sentiment Analysis might be another option, check out the [syuzhet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/syuzhet/index.html) package in R.

Comment: you can add the link as `[link](http://example.com)`, what is your **base point to decide the main responses are** ?, do you want classification of the sentences into positive and negative sentence?

Comment: you can always compute n-grams for your corpus and determine their frequency so that they can be displayed in a word cloud (or more accurately a phrase cloud).

Comment: Consider the discussion to this question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9886/classifying-survey-response-text-svm